# Simple php image upload not working on nginx (works on apache)

Tags: file-upload, nginx, upload, php

I'm new to nginx. This works on apache. I have nginx, PHP-FPM, Centos6.5 x64 installed using vpssim.

No file. directory is empty but script shows success. "Says Stored in example.jpg"

html

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload.php">
<input type="file" name="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
  $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  $extension = end($temp);
  if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
  && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 100000)
  && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
    {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
      {
      echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
      }
    else 
      {

        $fileName = $temp[0].".".$temp[1];
        $temp[0] = rand(0, 3000); //Set to random number
        $fileName;

      if (file_exists("" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
        {
        echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        }
      else
        {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        echo "Stored in: " . "" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        }
      }
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Invalid file";
    }
?>
```

Comment: then whats your problem

Comment: sorry. apache is my other server, this server has only nginx.

Comment: why don't you add upload directory and test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the answer. I got some help from here.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/365087/grant-a-user-permissions-on-www-data-owned-var-www

It was a group permission problem. I changed the permission for the group.

For normal nginx installation /home/example.com/public_html will not work. check your directory, probably /var/www/mysite/

For VPSSIM Installation. VPSSIM creates the group nginx by default.

How to solve:

Check your permission

```
ls -ld /home/example.com/public_html
```

get something like this

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root nginx 4096 Jan 24 21:06 /home/example.com/public_html
```

now change write permission for group nginx

```
sudo chmod -vR g+w /home/example.com/public_html
```

check changes

```
ls -ld /home/example.com/public_html

drwxrwxr-x 2 root nginx 4096 Jan 24 21:06 /home/example.com/public_html
```

to understand ls -ld check https://superuser.com/questions/171858/how-do-i-interpret-the-results-of-the-ls-l-command

Answer (score -1):

You can use the **Fix error Chmod, Chown** function in VPSSIM to fix that error.

VPSSIM menu ==> Tools - Addons (Option #16)  ==> Fix error Chmod, chown (Option #5) ==> Press Enter. 
Now everything will fine for you.

Comment: anh make server crash